# Get profile.name with Meteor.users.find()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I can get normal fields such as `_id` and `username` using:

```
users: function () {
      return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields:{_id:1,username:1}});
}
```

**But how do I get the `profile.name` that is from Facebook/Google/Twitter?**

Answer (score 2):

Use http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser hook to write `profile.name`.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    // We still want the default hook's 'profile' behavior.
    if (options.profile) {
        user.profile = options.profile;
        user.profile.memberSince = new Date();

        // Copy data from Facebook to user object
        user.profile.facebookId = user.services.facebook.id;
        user.profile.firstName = user.services.facebook.first_name;
        user.profile.email = user.services.facebook.email;
        user.profile.link = user.services.facebook.link;
    }

    return user;
});
```

[Getting Facebook Avatar in Meteor when Autopublish is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056552/getting-facebook-avatar-in-meteor-when-autopublish-is-removed)

Comment: But this gets called when a new user is created, not what I asked for. I know how to get the name by using `Meteor.user().profile.name` but that only gives the name from the current user, so I wanted to know that the field is called

Comment: Okay now I see that you mean, by checking the second link. However `profile.name` is already set, so there is no need to add it ourselfs